# ListView: textIsSelectable and onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, textview

#### Context

I have a list view where the row is basically composed of two TextView (*a title* and *a content*).

The second TextView can have a long text so I set `maxLines="6"`. When user click on the **row** I get rid of the `maxLines` in order to show the full text.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        TextView content = (TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.content);

        int limit = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.default_max_lines);

        if (content.getMaxLines() > limit) {
            content.setMaxLines(limit);
        }
        else {
            content.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
```

#### Problem

Above code works great. I would like to be able to select my second TextView (*content*) too so I set `android:textIsSelectable="true"` (also tried setting programmatically).

**But I can't expand/collapse my TextView because `onItemClick` is no longer called**

That's because `textIsSelectable` catches all click event...
From Android doc:

> When you call this method to set the value of textIsSelectable, it sets the flags focusable, focusableInTouchMode, clickable, and longClickable to the same value. These flags correspond to the attributes android:focusable, android:focusableInTouchMode, android:clickable, and android:longClickable. To restore any of these flags to a state you had set previously, call one or more of the following methods: setFocusable(), setFocusableInTouchMode(), setClickable() or setLongClickable().

I tried to set these flags to false after `setTextIsSelectable(true)` but I didn't manage to make it work.

**So, any ideas how to use both `textIsSelectable` and `onItemClick`?**

PS: Supporting only Android > 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled to the same problem and didn't fine any answer to this now 8 years old question.  My solution was as follows:

1. Set android:textIsSelectable="true" in the TextView
2. Don't set onItemClickListener to the ListView
3. Set OnClickListener in getView of the adapter to the TextView:

```
    override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        ...
        val listener = View.OnClickListener {
            ...
        }
        viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }
```

That enabled click on the TextView as well as selection of its text content.

Answer (score -4):

Use this below code It will works 100%

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
    text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
            // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
            // your listview

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

  }
```

you just use this code in your Mainactivity

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
  mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list);
mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```